# Decoding JWT and testing results in Postman

Tags: automated-testing, postman, jwt

We are implementing a new service which requires Authorisation by the way of a JWT.

I already have the submission and returned body containing the "access_token"

My question is how do I set up a call to decode the JWT (I have the following from a google search:)

> function jwt_decode(JWT) {
>       var parts = JWT.split('.'); // header, payload, signature
>       return JSON.parse(atob(parts[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3uhf.png)));
>   }

Once I have it decoded I then need to test that the relevant information is contained within.

I think I will need an environment/user file to store some variables but I'm not sure what I would need to store.

I currently have a "POST" to generate the "access_token", but not sure what to do next.  Do I need a "GET" to decode the JWT? What Authorisation do I need?

**EDIT**

So I've got my "access token" into an environment variable.  What I want to do now is decode the Access token and split it out so that I can confirm (Create Tests) the individual results in the Payload[image: Encoded and decoded JWT. I need to the the contents of the Payload section (circled in Red)]

Any comments or suggestions would be appreciated.  Can I do that within the same Post Call in postman, does it need a separate "POST" or "GET".  I'm a QA with little Javascript (if that's what Postman uses for testing) experience so please be clear in any replies.  Thanks

Comment: hi were you able to extract the token ? i believe know how you will use that token that token in request  ?

Comment: Hi, Yes I was able to get the token.

Comment: https://dev.to/loopdelicious/using-jwt-to-authenticate-and-authorize-requests-in-postman-3a5h   save it to a enviromental variable adn then call it from authorization header as {{<variablename>}}

Comment: Ok.  I have my access_token stored to my environment variable.  I have my Function to decode it (see above), which is on it's own "Get" tab, but as there it no url to call I don't see how I can get the access_token into the function to decode it.

Comment: i am not understanding what you actually want to do, if you want to reuse function, you can store function to an environmental variable adn run it using eval function

Comment: manually copy and paste the function to a enviromental variable say jwt_func. now call it from scripts as eval(pm.environment.get("jwt_func"));

Answer (score 10):

I am not sure what you want to do, if you are able to extract the access_token then i believe that you know to use the test script session  in postman

Assuming you have the access_token stored in environmental variable **swt**:

you can use the below code in the **same post request after you have stored the jwt to variable:** (Keep this code in "**Tests**" tab and not pre-requisite scripts)

```
 function jwt_decode(a) {
    var parts = a.split('.'); // header, payload, signature
    return JSON.parse(atob(parts[1]));
}

pm.test("validate data", function () {
    //Get the token
    var a=pm.environment.get("swt");
    
    //call your function to decode it
    let decodedData=jwt_decode(a);
    
    

    //print the decodedData to console to see the structure
    console.log(decodedData);
    
     //print the required field and print it to console to see the value
    console.log(decodedData.iss);
 
    //validate it using pm expect
    pm.expect(decodedData.iss).to.deep.equal("toptal.com");
});
```

you can open console by going to view>show postman console. Clear everything and click send again:

[image]

if you want to use the swt variable in other requests you can do it as below:

[image]

1. Goto "Authorization" tab
2. Select the authorization type you want, usually its **bearer token** for jwt
3. in the input field give **{{swt}}** (you can refer a variable anywhere in postman using the double curly bracket)

if you want to pass it as header , then go to header field and provide value as {{swt}} with correct 'Field' name

Comment: Thanks for you help.  I've got it working now. :-)

Comment: Could you accept the answer , and upvote

Answer (score 0):

## Decode part

Suppose your response looks like: `{ "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1Ni...`. Then just parse your "access_token" field in the Postman `Tests` tab:

```
var response = JSON.parse(responseBody);

var jwt_parts = response.access_token.split('.'); // header.payload.signature
var jwt_payload = JSON.parse(atob(jwt_parts[1]));
```

### Save part

Now you can either test or save data to..., let's say, an env. variable "sub".

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("sub", jwt_payload.sub);
```